# TypeORM Limit Not Working, Query returned one element in the array no matter what the limit is set?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, orm, typeorm

I am new to TypeORM. I have used `createQueryBuilder` to fetch data from database and used `.limit` function to set limit. But no matter what the limit is set in the query, only single entry in an array is returned in the result.

**code:**

```
           await this.createQueryBuilder()
            .select(['videoComment.id', 'videoComment.comment', 'videoComment.languageCode', 'videoComment.createdAt'
                , 'video.id', 'user.id', 'user.name', 'user.profileImage'])
            .from(VideoComment, 'videoComment')
            .innerJoin('videoComment.video', 'video', ' video.id = :videoId  and video.isActive = :isActive ')
            .innerJoin('videoComment.user', 'user')
            .where(' videoComment.id > :commentId ' +
                ' and videoComment.isActive = :isActive ', {
                videoId: videoId,
                commentId: commentId,
                isActive: isActive
            })
            .orderBy('videoComment.id')
            .limit(size.valueOf())
            .getMany();
```

**query generated:**

```
SELECT "videoComment"."id"            AS "videoComment_id",
       "videoComment"."created_at"    AS "videoComment_created_at",
       "videoComment"."comment"       AS "videoComment_comment",
       "videoComment"."language_code" AS "videoComment_language_code",
       "video"."id"                   AS "video_id",
       "user"."id"                    AS "user_id",
       "user"."name"                  AS "user_name",
       "user"."profile_image"         AS "user_profile_image"
FROM "video_comment" "VideoComment",
     "video_comment" "videoComment"
         INNER JOIN "video" "video"
                    ON "video"."id" = "videoComment"."video_id" AND ("video"."id" = $1 and "video"."is_active" = $2)
         INNER JOIN "user_detail" "user" ON "user"."id" = "videoComment"."user_id"
WHERE "videoComment"."id" > $3
  and "videoComment"."is_active" = $4
ORDER BY "videoComment"."id" ASC
LIMIT 5
```

query works fine when i am executing it on POSTGRES client. It returned the desired result. But in the application code it returns only single entry in the result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through SelectQueryBuilder.ts file i found:

```
/**
     * Set's LIMIT - maximum number of rows to be selected.
     * NOTE that it may not work as you expect if you are using joins.
     * If you want to implement pagination, and you are having join in your query,
     * then use instead take method instead.
     */
    limit(limit?: number): this;
```

So i used with `.take` function. It is giving the correct result but generating one extra query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "distinctAlias"."videoComment_id" as "ids_videoComment_id", "distinctAlias"."videoComment_id"
FROM (SELECT "videoComment"."id"            AS "videoComment_id",
             "videoComment"."created_at"    AS "videoComment_created_at",
             "videoComment"."comment"       AS "videoComment_comment",
             "videoComment"."language_code" AS "videoComment_language_code",
             "video"."id"                   AS "video_id",
             "user"."id"                    AS "user_id",
             "user"."name"                  AS "user_name",
             "user"."profile_image"         AS "user_profile_image"
      FROM "video_comment" "VideoComment",
           "video_comment" "videoComment"
               INNER JOIN "video" "video" ON "video"."id" = "videoComment"."video_id" AND
                                             ("video"."id" = $1 and "video"."is_active" = $2)
               INNER JOIN "user_detail" "user" ON "user"."id" = "videoComment"."user_id"
      WHERE "videoComment"."id" > $3
        and "videoComment"."is_active" = $4) "distinctAlias"
ORDER BY "distinctAlias"."videoComment_id" ASC, "videoComment_id" ASC
LIMIT 5
    
SELECT "videoComment"."id"            AS "videoComment_id",
       "videoComment"."created_at"    AS "videoComment_created_at",
       "videoComment"."comment"       AS "videoComment_comment",
       "videoComment"."language_code" AS "videoComment_language_code",
       "video"."id"                   AS "video_id",
       "user"."id"                    AS "user_id",
       "user"."name"                  AS "user_name",
       "user"."profile_image"         AS "user_profile_image"
FROM "video_comment" "VideoComment",
     "video_comment" "videoComment"
         INNER JOIN "video" "video"
                    ON "video"."id" = "videoComment"."video_id" AND ("video"."id" = $1 and "video"."is_active" = $2)
         INNER JOIN "user_detail" "user" ON "user"."id" = "videoComment"."user_id"
WHERE ("videoComment"."id" > $3 and "videoComment"."is_active" = $4)
  AND "videoComment"."id" IN ($5, $6, $7, $8, $9)
ORDER BY "videoComment"."id" ASC
```

It is first getting the distinct ids and then using these ids to fetch the actual result set which was queried. This seems less efficient as one extra query is executed but solved the problem.